# Different ports in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, service

I am trying to understand the difference between different ports in kubernetes visually. This is the visual sketch which I could understand;
Whenever, a traffic comes to service at `port`, it sends traffic to `targetPort`  where pod is exposed and finally traffic is sent to `containerPort` from `targetPort`.

Is it the right visualization?
[image]